# How can I access objects in a django model composed of two foreign keys?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

These are the relevant classes of my app. I want basically understand if the a certain user (form AuthUser) is linked to a business (from BusinessInformation) by looking at UserBusinessInformation. Thanks

```
class AuthUser(models.Model):
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_superuser = models.IntegerField()
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    is_staff = models.IntegerField()
    is_active = models.IntegerField()
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_user'

class BusinessInformation(models.Model):
    business_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    lat = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    lng = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    formatted_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    locality = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    administrative_area_level_5 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    administrative_area_level_4 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    administrative_area_level_3 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    administrative_area_level_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    administrative_area_level_1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    route = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    street_number = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    phone2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    phone3 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    email2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    email3 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    facebook = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'business_information'

class UserBusinessInformation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING)
    business = models.ForeignKey(BusinessInformation, models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'user_business_information'
```

When I try to access to UserBusinessInformation in my views, I do not manage neither using _set.

```
def school(request, schoolname):
    school_searched = BusinessInformation.objects.get(name=schoolname)
    user_linked = school_searched.userbusinessinformation_set.all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I miss the many to many field:

```
class BusinessInformation(models.Model):
    business_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(AuthUser, 
                                   through='UserBusinessInformation')
    ...
```

Then, in your view:

```
def school(request, schoolname):
    school_searched = BusinessInformation.objects.get(name=schoolname)
    user_linked = school_searched.users.all()
```

Quoting [Extra fields on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) django docs:

> For these situations, Django allows you to specify the model that will be used to govern the many-to-many relationship. You can then put extra fields on the intermediate model. The intermediate model is associated with the ManyToManyField using the through argument to point to the model that will act as an intermediary.

Let me finish with a little advice, it is true, *'These are the relevant classes of my app'*, but you can illustrate this sample with just few fields. Learn about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: thanks for the answer that is exactly what I needed, and thanks for the advice - that I will try to follow

Answer (score 1):

```
[if you want access a field that’s a ForeignKey, you’ll get the related model object just like]

    from django.db import models

       class Publisher(models.Model):
           name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
           address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
           city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
           state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
           country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
           website = models.URLField()`enter code here`
           def __str__(self):
              return self.name

        class Author(models.Model):
          first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
          last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
          email = models.EmailField()

          def __str__(self):
              return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

        class Book(models.Model):
            title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
            authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
            publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
            publication_date = models.DateField()

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title 

    [you can access like that.... ]

    b = Book.objects.get(id=50)
    b.publisher
    b.publisher.website
```